# Java remote debugging: maven 2.2.1

Tags: java, eclipse

Hi: I have a multithreading J2SE application and using maven and my IDE is eclipse. In maven 2.2.1, there is mvnDebug which open port 8000 as remote port.

I run mvn `-clean test -Dtest=TestClass`

Then I configure Eclipse remote Java application and put host as `localhost`, port `8000`, attach type.

The I put breakpoint in `TestClass`. The problem/questions is that `mvn` command run through without stop at break point at all. I tried break point as suspending thread or suspending JVM. Neither works.

Could someone in this forum give me some hints which step I missed?

Comment: Can you pastebin the output of maven ?

Comment: Actually I run mvnDebug -clean test -Dtest=TestClass

Comment: @autra: What pastebin means? Do you want output after mavenDebug clean test -Dtest=TestClass?

Comment: check out pastebin.com, it is a website that allow to paste and copy large bunch of text. You create a new one and put here the url. and yes I want the output of maven.

Comment: There are something like here:http://pastebin.com/eDGq6hGH

Answer (score 4):

Here is the command I use:

```
mvn test -Dtest=TestClass -Dmaven.surefire.debug="-Xdebug -Xrunjdwp:transport=dt_socket,server=y,suspend=y,address=8000 -Xnoagent -Djava.compiler=NONE"
```

- `address=8000` defines adress for JDB
- `suspend=y` defines that JVM will stop on startup and wait for debugger to connect. Set to `n` to start as usual, without stopping. This options may be useful if you want to debug context startup.

Comment: Isn't it same as mvnDebug? Anyway, I will have a try.

Comment: I believe it is a bit different. mvnDebug starts maven in debug mode, but my command starts only tests in debug mode. (Surefire runs new process for tests).

Comment: But I got error "Failed to connect to remote VM. Connection refused.
Connection refused: connect".

Comment: It even does not have "Preparing to Execute Maven in Debug Mode
Listening for transport dt_socket at address: 8000"

Comment: In order for -Dmaven.surefire.debug working, what else shall I do?

Comment: Do you use surefire for tests?

Answer (score 2):

try surefire plugin
mvn clean test -Dmaven.surefire.debug